ESP32 as CAN Bus Master with Multiple Arduino Slave Nodes (MCP2515) – Single Dashboard Control?
I’m working on a project where I plan to use an ESP32 with a TJA1050 (CAN transceiver) as the master node in a CAN bus network. The ESP32 will serve as the main IoT node, controlling several Arduino boards (up to 5) connected to the same CAN bus.
Each Arduino will be interfaced to the CAN bus using an external CAN driver circuit consisting of the MCP2515 (CAN controller) and TJA1050 (CAN transceiver). The goal is for the ESP32 to both transmit and receive data (TX/RX) from these Arduino nodes, while also controlling certain functions on each Arduino.
Additionally, I want to create a web-based dashboard hosted on the ESP32, allowing me to control and monitor all the Arduino nodes from a single page.
Key Points:
ESP32 as the CAN bus master node (with TJA1050).
Arduinos as slave nodes using MCP2515-TJA1050 combinations.
Up to 5 Arduino nodes on the CAN bus.
Web-based dashboard on the ESP32 to control and access all Arduino functions and data.
Questions:

Is it possible to control all the Arduino nodes (TX/RX functions) via a single dashboard on the ESP32?

What are the best practices for setting up the CAN bus and ensuring reliable communication between the ESP32 and the Arduino nodes?

How would I structure the communication protocol between the ESP32 (master) and the Arduino slaves to ensure commands are sent and received correctly?


I’ve attached a flow diagram for better understanding.



Is it possible to control all the Arduino nodes (TX/RX functions) via a single dashboard on the ESP32?

Obviously it is possible, though using external CAN controllers like the MCP2515 old-timer is last resort to be avoided. You'll only use that when you have very special requirements forcing you to use one particular MCU, which in turn doesn't have a CAN controller, which is something that's been available for MCUs since somewhere around year 2000. Don't use 1990s designs in new projects unless there is a reason for it.
As for Arduino, it is not suitable for any purpose - neither for learning nor for  professional use. It is particularly unsuitable in this case if it doesn't even come with built-in CAN controller.
Also, stop thinking in terms of TX and RX. In CAN, all frames are broadcasted to all nodes, always. It is data driven - the identifiers of the frames is what give them meaning. Nodes that aren't interested in certain identifiers simply discard them.

What are the best practices for setting up the CAN bus and ensuring reliable communication between the ESP32 and the Arduino nodes?

That's an overly broad question. The most basic things like baudrate, CAN identifier length and termination resistors need to be considered first.
Some basic things to avoid can be found here: What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors? Stubs, missing signal GND, bad clock source etc etc.

How would I structure the communication protocol between the ESP32 (master) and the Arduino slaves to ensure commands are sent and received correctly?

Nobody can answer that without a real-time specification. It's about what latency that's acceptable, how many frames you need to send per second etc.
When making a home-brewed CAN protocol it is good to look at best practices used in existing CAN protocols like CANopen. For example you might want to send data always every n milliseconds rather than only sending it upon change. You also need to group all frames so that identifiers for the most important frames have the lowest number, meaning they get prioritized in case of bus problems.
You also have to consider how to assign node id to the slaves. Is it programmable or do you need something like a dip-switch per node etc.
Another nice thing from CANopen is to create a sync message. That is: the master first sends out the data for the slaves to act upon. The slaves store the data. Then the master sends out a sync message at a given time interval. Upon receiving that one, all slaves set their output. It gives the system a simple clocking mechanism with some <ms accuracy at least. Instead of having all slaves running around in the wild with individual actions based on their own local clocks.
